# Cant convert image from db to FIBITMAP(freee image)

Tags: c#, bitmap, freeimage

i have db with images in  the byte array format. I need to upload particular image from there and compressed by free image methods. But first of all need to convert my byte array to FIBITMAP format.My code:

```
string user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ApplicationUser au = db.Users.Include(t => t.Pictures).FirstOrDefault(t => (t.Id) == user);
        Picture pic = au.Pictures.Where(p => p.Id == id).First();
FIBITMAP dib = FreeImage.LoadFromStream(new MemoryStream(pic.Image));
```

Error is a :

> An exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in FreeImageNET.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

in the documents wrote

> 

public static FIBITMAP LoadFromStream(
    Stream stream
)

> Parameters
>   stream
>   Type: System.IO.Stream
>   The stream to read from.
>   Return Value
>   Handle to a FreeImage bitmap.

I cant understand where is my mistake, btw i tried to use load/loadBitmap etc. with different variatons of my array(i converted it to bitmap). Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FreeImage on C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432041/freeimage-on-c-sharp)

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 no, thats not similar, on my solution dll is work